# Interval of concavity?

Tags: calculus

... for

$$ f''(x) = \frac{-6}{(x - 2)^3}$$

I know there are no points of inflection, because the function cannot equal zero, but are there still intervals of concavity?

Comment: The thing to keep in mind is that, while the second derivative can change sign at zeroes, it can also change sign when its denominator is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the second derivative is negative in $(2,\infty)$, so $f$ is concave down there. It is concave up in $(-\infty,2)$.